# Does physical equilibrium occur at specific temperature and pressure?

Tags: pressure, temperature, physical-chemistry, equilibrium

Does physical equilibrium occur at only specific temperature and pressure? Like does equilibrium occur only at $ 1 atm $ and $0⁰C$ between water and ice? If I change temperature or pressure will the physical equilibrium again establish at different concentration? Also is it the same for dissolution of solids
and gases in liquids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Clausius-Clapeyron equation you only have one degree of freedom (one species case, e.g., pure Nitrogen). If you want to preserve both phases, changing the temperature will automatically change the pressure. Otherwise you will end up with only one phase.

This is of course different for mixtures (e.g. Nitrogen and Oxygen), where a change in temperature may be performed with constant pressure and changing concentration during phase equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

See the [phase diagram of water](https://www.chemistrylearner.com/phase-diagram-of-water.html).  Solid/Liquid, Liquid/Gas, or Solid/Gas equilibrium can exist anywhere on the red curves between the phases. There is even a triple point where Solid/Liquid/Gas can all exist in equilibrium simultaneously.

If you take a closed container of water and heat it to say 50 °C, liquid will slowly evaporate until the gas pressure reaches its equilibrium pressure. If you leave the container open, the liquid will keep evaporating until it is all gone, because it is attempting to reach this equilibrium but cannot build up any pressure.

When we say the "freezing point of water" is 0 °C, that means "at 1 atm pressure" i.e. at sea level. On a mountaintop (lower pressure), that equilibrium temperature would be different.